# Add dummy columns in transposed dataset - sas

Tags: sas

I have transposed data set

```
ID        PA_1        PA_2
-------------------------------   
1        user1      user2          
2        user3      user4           
3        user5      'NULL'         
4        user6      user7
```

Target data set

```
ID        PA_1        PA_2        PA_2        PA_2        PA_2        PA_2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------      
1        
2        
3        
4
```

Since the first table is the result of a `proc transpose`, it could have less columns (like `ID`, `PA_1`, `PA_2`) or more (like `ID`, `PA_1`, `PA_2`, `PA_3`, `PA_4`, `PA_5`, `PA_6`)

When I try to join both tables by the ID, since there is no other columns other than PA_1 and PA_2, the query fails.

Need a solution to this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Please add the code you use to join them and the way you see it fails.

Comment: Columns with the same name in a data set get overridden. ie if you join a table with ID, A1 and ID, A1, A2 your final output is a table with ID, A1, A2 and A1 is from the last table. Show your code and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have 2 datasets, ds_01 (with PA_1 and PA_2) and ds_02 (with PA_1, PA_2, PA_3 and PA_4)

To get the same variables in both datasets, you can do this little hack:

```
data ds_01 ds_02;
    set ds_01(in=a)
        ds_02(in=b)
    ;
    
    if a then output ds_01;
    if b then output ds_02;
run;
```

Like this, you read both datasets and force the creation of the SAS PDV with all variables from both datasets.

With the conditional output, you recreate the datasets with the same values, but this time with all variables from either ds_01 or ds_02.